# Js - запуск функции при нажатии кнопки "назад"

Tags: javascript, iframe, навигация

Привет.

На главной странице в иФрейм загружается игра. Внутри игры еще два уровня фреймов... как сделать, чтобы при нажатии кнопки "назад" в браузере, не возвращаться на предыдущую страничку, а выполнять функцию скрывающую открытый фрейм?

Comment: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+назад](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4)

Comment: Победил... добавил на ссылки открывающие ифрейм якоря. А в страничку ифрейма вставил onbeforeunload который релоадит родительскую страницу... Ход не гениальный, но работает.